# Add a poster frame to a loaded video

Tags: actionscript-3, flv, flvplayback, streaming-flv-video, poster

I'm building application where users can upload `flv`'s with the `fileReference`. 
When a user press upload the `flv` is uploaded into a folder and the path stored into the database.

When the user clicks on an other page, he can see a list with all the uploaded movies. 
But I want to create custom control for the movie so the user can click one to play.

How can I add a 'poster' from the first or a random frame from the `flv`?

*There is no option to create a `png` for each file because when the app is online user can pick there own `flv`s to upload.*

Answer (score 0):

Spark's [`VideoDisplay`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/VideoDisplay.html) has a property called `autoDisplayFirstFrame` which would do what you want.

If you can't use Flex, you could try to mimic the code of this component : http://pastebin.com/5TDZzEvJ